# Я не могу понять как использовать переменную в конструкторе производного класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Вот мои два класса, подскажите как использовать переменную  int m_charge в конструкторе производного класса Videoplayer, выбивает ошибку

```
class CDevice
    {
    protected:
        int m_charge;
        string ptr_DeviceName;
    public:
        CDevice()
        {
            cout << ""<<endl;
        }
        virtual ~CDevice()
        {
            cout << "" << endl;
        }
        CDevice(int charge, string DeviceName)
            : m_charge(charge), ptr_DeviceName(DeviceName)
        {
        }

    void Setcharge(int m_charge)
    {
        this->m_charge = m_charge;
    }
    void SetDevicename(string ptr_DeviceName)
    {
        this->ptr_DeviceName = ptr_DeviceName;
    }
    virtual void ShowInformation() = 0;

};
class CVideoplayer :virtual public CDevice
{
private:
    int m_quality;
    string ptr_Videoname;
public:
    CVideoplayer(int quality, string Videoname, int Charge)
        :m_quality(quality), ptr_Videoname(Videoname), m_charge(Charge)
    {
    }
    
    void Setquality(int m_quality)
    {
        this->m_quality = m_quality;
    }
    int Getquality()
    {
        return m_quality;
    }
    void SetVideoname(string ptr_Videoname)
    {
        this->ptr_Videoname = ptr_Videoname;
    }
    string GetVideoname()
    {
        return ptr_Videoname;
    }
    void ShowInformation()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << ptr_Videoname << endl;
        cout << "Quality: " << m_quality << endl;
        cout << "Charge: " <<  << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    CVideoplayer ch(720, "Mark", 7);
    ch.ShowInformation();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструировать чужие переменные нельзя. Только попозже в теле конструктора вы можете переменную модифицировать.

Порядок инициализации объекта :

```
class A{
public :
  A ( ) : p { 0 } { }
protected :
  int p ;
  };
class B : public A {
public :
  B ( ) : A { } , i { } { p = 1 ; }
  int i;
  };
```

При создании объекта B сначала вызывается конструктор A. *В конструкторе A все личные переменные будут **уже** инициализированы*. Затем у локальных переменных класса B. После всех вызовов конструкторов вы можете модифицировать *(не инициализировать)* переменную у базового класса.

У вас это так :

```
CVideoplayer(int quality, string Videoname, int Charge)
    :m_quality(quality), ptr_Videoname(Videoname)
{
  m_charge = Charge ;
}
```

Сначала будет вызван конструктор по-умолчанию `CDevice::CDevice()`, потом вы проставите свои переменные и дальше модифицируете `m_charge`.

Или можно создать конструктор в базовом классе, принимающий один аргумент `charge`. Тогда просто отдайте этот аргумент ему.

```
CDevice(int c):m_charge(c)
    { }

CVideoplayer(int quality, string Videoname, int Charge)
    :CDevice(Charge),m_quality(quality), ptr_Videoname(Videoname)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вызывайте весь конструктор базового класса:

```
CVideoplayer(int quality, string Videoname, int Charge)
        :CDevice(Charge, ""), m_quality(quality), ptr_Videoname(Videoname)
{
}
```